# World's largest 3D archery course?

Tags: archery

Do we know which is the world's largest 3D archery course and its stats? Depending on the trail length and the count of targets.

Comment: Title is kinda vague

Comment: Biggest as in size in square miles / km or biggest as in most popular? Usually these go hand in hand but not always...

Comment: As I said: trail length and number of targets =)

Comment: I think they all go between 25 to 40 targets being 40 the longest I've been. I guess they stay around this size due to huge organizing time and long time in the course. A 30 target course usually takes a good 2 hours. I don't know the longest (hence a comment instead of an answer) but I'm sure a club could organize a full day 50+ targets but I don't think it would happen regularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is/was probably at the [2014 National NASP Tournament – a certified Guinness World Book record – for the world’s largest archery tournament. Held in Louisville’s Exposition Center, 10,800 student-archers from grades 4 through 12 representing 39 states, including Alaska, competed.](http://www.kentuckytourism.com/articles/kentucky-competitions-right-on-target-for-archers/2099/)

Google offers some other suggestions, but this looks like the best candidate. Other then the "Guinness World Book record" I am not finding details on size.